# How do I have a create a signed in user before running an Rspec feature test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to write a feature test (using Rspec 3 and Capybara) that tests a user adding an address (string) and getting the coordinates in response. Users need to be signed in before they can do this, so how can I create a user and then perform this function? I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: fill_in 'text_field_tag', with: q

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "text_field_tag" that is not disabled
```

Here is the code I have so far.

find_coordinates_spec.rb

```
feature 'find coordinates' do
  scenario 'with valid place name' do
    user = User.create(email: 'test@test.com', password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
    sign_in user
    geocode('London')
    expect(page).to have_content('51.5073219, -0.1276474')
  end

  def geocode(q)
    visit locations_path
    fill_in 'text_field_tag', with: q
    click_button 'geocode'
  end
end
```

locations_controller.rb

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if params[:q].blank?
      @message = 'Please enter an address in the field!'
      return
    end

    token = Rails.application.credentials.locationiq_key
    search = LocationiqApi.new(token).find_place(params[:q])

    # Hash#dig will return nil if ANY part of the lookup fails
    latitude = search.dig('searchresults', 'place', 'lat')
    longitude = search.dig('searchresults', 'place', 'lon')

    if latitude.nil? || longitude.nil?
      # Output an error message if lat or lon is nil
      @coordinates = "We couldn't find a place by this name. Please enter a valid place name."
    else
      @coordinates = "Coordinates: " + "#{latitude}, #{longitude}"
    end
  end
end
```

locations.html.erb

```
<main>
  <h1>Location Search</h1>
  <!-- devise flash messages -->
  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  <!-- Button to search coordinates -->
  <%= form_tag(locations_path, method: :get) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("geocode") %>
    <%= @message %>
  <% end %><br>

  <%= @coordinates %>
</main>
```

Comment: Include capybara tag if your questions are related to it.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Okay, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is not because of failure to create a user.
Just to be sure that authentication went ok you can add after `visit locations_path`:

```rb
  expect(page).to have_content('Please enter an address in the field')
```

Actual error is that your input field is called `q` and not `text_field_tag`:

```
  fill_in "q", with: q
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting this error because of this line:

```
fill_in 'text_field_tag', with: q
```

According to Capybara documentation on `#fill_in`:

> The field can be found via its name, id, Capybara.test_id attribute, or label text

`text_field_tag` is not an html attribute but a rails view helper. You should change if with the id, label or name of the `text_field_tag`